# Apache Tomcat 9 does no more run on local IP address since Windows 10 version 2004

Tags: java, tomcat, windows-10

I am developing a web application with Apache Tomcat 9. That was running fine with Windows 10 version 1809: Entering

```
http://{my-local-ipadress}:{portnumer}/{path}
```

or entering

```
http://localhost:{portnumer}/{path}
```

connected to the web service.

I have a DNS address from https://no-ip.com, so I could also enter

```
http://{my-dns-address}:{port}/{path}
```

, as my DNS address is mapped to my local IP address. And a mobile-app could connect to my DNS address. Now since upgrade to Windows 10 version 2004 (I am not completely sure whether that is the reason),

```
http://localhost:{portnumer}/{path}
```

still works, but

```
http://{my-local-ipadress}:{portnumer}/{path}
```

gets a timeout (of course I have started the service in Eclipse). And of course the mobile app cannot connect my `http://localhost` . Do you have an idea how to solve that?

Comment: You missing client-software what support No IP.

Comment: NoIP translates my current local IP address (10.20.30.40) into the registered address myaddress.hopto.org. That still works.
But tomcat is no more reachable with http://10.20.30.40:8080 (though it is running of course, and it is accessible with http://localhost:8080), then NoIP has no chance. And it worked up to last week (Windows 10 1809). 
Anything must have changed, maybe with Windows upgrade, maybe anything else.